# POSTing JSON object to Spring Controller and validating with nested objects

Tags: java, json, spring, validation

I'm trying to validate nested objects being POSTed through jQuery.

Here are my objects:

```
public class One {

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    Two two;

    public Two getTwo() {
        return two;
    }

    public void setTwo(Two two) {
        this.two = two;
    }

}
```

and

```
public class Two {

    @NotNull
    private String property;

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    public void setProperty(String property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

}
```

and here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String test(@Valid One one) {
    return "Success";
}
```

However, I am POSTing the following JSON object:

```
{
    "two": {
        "property": "test"
    }
}
```

and I get the error: `Field error in object 'one' on field 'two': rejected value [null]; codes [NotNull.one.two,NotNull.two,NotNull.com.test.Two,NotNull]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [one.two,two]; arguments []; default message [two]]; default message [may not be null]`

Is there something wrong with my JSON structure or is there something I am missing?

**EDIT**
Here is the jQuery ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'my-url-here',
        data: JSON.stringify({"one":{"two":{"property": "test"}}}),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json'
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong besides the JSON object you are posting. The error is exactly what it should be. You are receiving One that MUST have an object Two as NotNull. And you are sending just an object Two. How do you want it to pass? Try sending: `{"one":{"two":{"property": "test"}}}`

Comment: @JorgeCampos this yields the same result

Comment: Change your `@RequestMapping` to `@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"application/json"})`

Comment: @JorgeCampos Still getting the same error (for both your recommended structure and my original)

Comment: Well there should be something wrong with your spring setup then.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I don't believe so, the validation works for non-nested objects so I think Spring is configured OK.

Comment: Try to remove the annotations then and test it. (@Valid and @NotNull) and see what happens

Comment: @JorgeCampos It doesn't throw any errors, however the "Two" object is null

Comment: Ok, that is a clue. Add in object One a constructor that receives the object Two and also a default constructor (whitout any parameters) and see how it works

Comment: Nope, still no luck

Comment: @JorgeCampos Hm...if I pass in the data as a query string, it works. So for the example above, if I add ?two.property=test it works. But not if I post the json object as the request body

Comment: Last Ideia that I can think of: `public String test(@RequestBody One one)` without the `@ResponseBody` annotation on it. Also with the consumes...app/json

Comment: @JorgeCampos That did it! `@RequestBody` seemed to be the issue. If you add this as an answer, I will accept

Comment: Ok. I will add it.

Comment: Did you tested it with the notnull annotation ? to see if it validate the object?

Comment: Yes, that was tested with `@Valid and @NotNull` Everything is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method to:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes={"application/json"})
public String test(@RequestBody One one)
```

Comment: I had to add back `@Valid` to `One one` but ultimately this fixed my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that I could help :)